# How more correctly make Helper in VueJs?

Tags: vue.js

I have some method to generate random hexademical color. It will be used in very few (3 or 5) parts of the project. So I want to separate it from main code into some kind of Helper or smth else, and include it when needed (not globally).

I have 2 working ways to do this:

- Using mixins. What I don't like is that when you read the code, you can't separate your own methods from methods of mixin.
- Using plugins. What I don't like with that is that you have to write  `import Vue from 'vue'` + `Vue.use(MyPlugin)` every time in all files where you want to use it. After that, you can call it like this.$ColorHelper.getRandomHEX().

So, the question is about aesthetics visualization. 
What is the best practices to do such things?

PS: project was created from template with webpack.

Comment: You can use "renderless" component also. It is my preferred approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our team decide use function import from files-helpers
For example:

```
import { getRandomColor, getBackgroundColor } from 'Global/helpers/colorHelper';
// .....
let color = getRandomColor();
```

**What good:**

- Don't need use excess  import + use as in plugins
- Method visually stands out, what it not from `this`

**What bad:**

- Cant see visually what the helper have method. But possible can fixed with aliases. We dont think yet

Answer (score 0):

Vue plugins are global, you only have to call the `Vue.use` method once. Then they should work wherever you use that particular Vue instance.

In a default project setup you normally don't have multiple Vue instance so it should work globally.

From the docs:

> Plugins usually add global-level functionality to Vue.

And:

> Use plugins by calling the Vue.use() global method:

```
Vue.use(MyPlugin)
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html

Comment: I cant use Vue variable globaly: Uncaught ReferenceError: `Vue is not defined.`

How works plugins - yes, I know :)

Comment: You use this at the same exact location where you have imported Vue. This is not a global. You do this before you create a new Vue instance with `new Vue()`. If Vue is not defined there than you wouldn't even be able to instantiate it.